# How to retrieve data based checkbox selection using json in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How to filter checkbox based on two json array objects in angularjs, here key same for the comp1 and comp2. How to push selected this two json objects into one array.

```
var comp1=
[
  {
    "ID": "GROUP",
    "Name": "client ",
    "ListItemID": "GROUP",
    "ListItemUniqueId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "isSelected": true
  },
  {
    "ID": "co1",
    "Name": "comp1",
    "ListItemID": "3",
    "ListItemUniqueId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "isSelected": true
  }];
var comp2=[
  {
    "Access": null,
    "AuditFile": null,
    "CurrentItem": null,
    "DAPSortOrder": 1,
    "DocName": null,
    "DocTitle": null,
    "DocUrl": null,
    "EnableComponent": false,
    "Id": 1,
    "ImageUrl": null,
    "PeriodName": "Planning",
    "RelatesTo": co1,
    "created": null,
    "type": null
  }];
```

Comment: This needs a bit of clarification. Perhaps posting your HTML code would help.

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash union() and filter() function.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#union

https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#filter

```
var newArray = filter( join(comp1, comp2), function (item) {
     return item.isSelected || item.PeriodName; // any condition you need
});
```